# Can't include a dropdownlist in the ribbon

Tags: ribbon

I'm trying to add a custom dropdownlist in the publishing rich editor control of SharePoint.

Basically, my goal is to set a specific class and a specific data value on an hyperlink. This will be handled by a jQuery plugin in another script.

My dropdown list should provides :

- "Default": `<a href="somewhere">Teleport</a>`
- "Value 1": `<a href="somewhere" class="myplugin" data-myplugin="1">Teleport</a>`
- "Value 2": `<a href="somewhere" class="myplugin" data-myplugin="2">Teleport</a>`

and so on.

However, my drop down does not even appears in the ribbon.

As I want to setup link, I plugged my drop down within the link editing tab.

I'm quite sure my Ids are correct, because I also added a checkbox that *is* visible. This checkbox is similar as it will also toggle a specific css class.
This checkbox works as expected.

Here is my custom action definition :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<Elements xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/sharepoint/">
  <CustomAction
    Id="MyProject.RichEditorCustomisation"
    Location="CommandUI.Ribbon"
    Title="[Me] Customation Rich Editor">
    <CommandUIExtension>
      <CommandUIDefinitions>
        <CommandUIDefinition
          Location="Ribbon.Link.Link.Behavior.Controls._children">
          <CheckBox Command="MyProject.Ribbon.PageComponent.ToggleMyClass"
                    QueryCommand="MyProject.Ribbon.PageComponent.QueryToggleMyClass"
                    LabelText="toggle myclass"
                    Id="MyProject.RichEditorCustomisation.ToggleMyClass"
                    Sequence="30"
                    Alt="TODO"
                    TemplateAlias="o1" />
        </CommandUIDefinition>
        <CommandUIDefinition
          Location="Ribbon.Link.Link.Behavior.Controls._children">
          <DropDown 
                    Id="MyProject.RichEditorCustomisation.SetupMyPlugin"
                    Command="MyProject.Ribbon.PageComponent.DoSetupMyPlugin"
                    QueryCommand="MyProject.Ribbon.PageComponent.QuerySetupMyPlugin"
                    Sequence="31" Width="200px"
                    Alt="TODO"
                    TemplateAlias="dd1" >
            <Menu Id="MyProject.RichEditorCustomisation.SetupMyPlugin.Menu">
              <MenuSection Id="MyProject.RichEditorCustomisation.SetupMyPlugin.Menu.Section">
                <Controls Id="MyProject.RichEditorCustomisation.SetupMyPlugin.Menu.Section.Controls">
                  <Button  Id="MyProject.RichEditorCustomisation.SetupMyPlugin.DefaultButton"
                           Command="MyProject.Ribbon.PageComponent.SetupMyPlugin"
                           LabelText="Default" CommandValueId="0" 
                           />
                  <Button  Id="MyProject.RichEditorCustomisation.SetupMyPlugin.NewWindowButton"
                           Command="MyProject.Ribbon.PageComponent.SetupMyPlugin"
                           LabelText="Value 1" CommandValueId="1" 
                           />
                </Controls>
              </MenuSection>
            </Menu>
          </DropDown>
        </CommandUIDefinition>
      </CommandUIDefinitions>
    </CommandUIExtension>
  </CustomAction>
</Elements>
```

And here is my javascript file :

```
ExecuteOrDelayUntilScriptLoaded(
    function () {
        Type.registerNamespace("MyProject.RichEditorCustomisation");

        MyProject.RichEditorCustomisation.PageComponent = function () {
            MyProject.RichEditorCustomisation.PageComponent.initializeBase(this);
        };

        MyProject.RichEditorCustomisation.PageComponent.prototype = {
            commands: null,
            init: function () { },
            buildCommands: function () {
                if (SP.ScriptUtility.isNullOrUndefined(this.commands)) {
                    this.commands = [];
                    this.commands.push('MyProject.Ribbon.PageComponent.ToggleMyClass');
                    this.commands.push('MyProject.Ribbon.PageComponent.QueryToggleMyClass');
                    this.commands.push('MyProject.Ribbon.PageComponent.SetupMyPlugin');
                    this.commands.push('MyProject.Ribbon.PageComponent.DoSetupMyPlugin');
                    this.commands.push('MyProject.Ribbon.PageComponent.QuerySetupMyPlugin');
                }

                return this.commands;
            },
            getGlobalCommands: function () {
                return this.buildCommands();
            },
            canHandleCommand: function (commandId) {
                return true;
            },
            handleCommand: function (commandId, properties, sequence) {
                switch (commandId) {
                    case "MyProject.Ribbon.PageComponent.ToggleMyClass":
                        this.ToggleMyClass(properties[CUI.Controls.CheckBoxCommandProperties.On]);
                        break;
                    case "MyProject.Ribbon.PageComponent.QueryToggleMyClass":
                        properties[CUI.Controls.ToggleButtonCommandProperties.On] = this.isMyClassApplied();
                        break;
                    case "MyProject.Ribbon.PageComponent.DoSetupMyPlugin":
                        // Nothing to do ?!?!?
                        break;
                    case "MyProject.Ribbon.PageComponent.SetupMyPlugin":
                        setMyPluginValue(properties[CUI.Controls.DropDownCommandProperties.Value]);
                        break;
                    case "MyProject.Ribbon.PageComponent.QuerySetupMyPlugin":
                        properties[CUI.Controls.DropDownCommandProperties.Value] = getmyPluginValue();
                        break;
                }
                return true;
            },
            ToggleMyClass: function (hasMyClass) {
                var link = RTE.CanvasEvents.getNodeFromEvent('Link');
                if (!link) {
                    return;
                }
                RTE.SnapshotManager.takeSnapshot();
                if (hasMyClass) {
                    jQuery(link).addClass("myclass");
                }
                else {
                    jQuery(link).removeClass("myclass");
                }
                RTE.SnapshotManager.takeSnapshot();
            },
            isMyClassApplied: function () {
                var link = RTE.CanvasEvents.getNodeFromEvent('Link');
                return jQuery(link).hasClass("myclass");
            },
            setMyPluginValue: function (myPluginValue) {
                var link = RTE.CanvasEvents.getNodeFromEvent('Link');
                if (!link) {
                    return;
                }
                RTE.SnapshotManager.takeSnapshot();
                if (myPluginValue && myPluginValue != 0) {
                    jQuery(link).addClass("myplugin").data("mypluginvalue", myPluginValue);
                } else {
                    jQuery(link).removeClass("myplugin").removeData("myPluginValue");
                }
                RTE.SnapshotManager.takeSnapshot();
            },
            getmyPluginValue: function () {
                var link = RTE.CanvasEvents.getNodeFromEvent('Link');
                var $link = jQuery(link);
                var myPluginValue = $link.data("myPluginValue");
                if ($link.hasClass("myplugin") && myPluginValue > 0) return myPluginValue;
                else return 0;
            }
        }

        MyProject.RichEditorCustomisation.PageComponent.get_instance = function () {
            if (SP.ScriptUtility.isNullOrUndefined(MyProject.RichEditorCustomisation.PageComponent.singleton))
                MyProject.RichEditorCustomisation.PageComponent.singleton = new MyProject.RichEditorCustomisation.PageComponent();

            return MyProject.RichEditorCustomisation.PageComponent.singleton;
        }

        MyProject.RichEditorCustomisation.PageComponent.registerWithPageManager = function () {
            SP.Ribbon.PageManager.get_instance().addPageComponent(MyProject.RichEditorCustomisation.PageComponent.get_instance());
        }

        MyProject.RichEditorCustomisation.PageComponent.unregisterWithPageManager = function () {
            if (SP.ScriptUtility.isNullOrUndefined(MyProject.RichEditorCustomisation.PageComponent.singleton) == false)
                SP.Ribbon.PageManager.get_instance().removePageComponent(MyProject.RichEditorCustomisation.PageComponent.get_instance());
        }

        MyProject.RichEditorCustomisation.PageComponent.registerClass("MyProject.RichEditorCustomisation.PageComponent", CUI.Page.PageComponent);
        MyProject.RichEditorCustomisation.PageComponent.registerWithPageManager();
        NotifyScriptLoadedAndExecuteWaitingJobs("RichEditorCustomisation.js");
    }
, 'SP.Ribbon.js');
```

I can't see what's missing or wrong in my Xml declaration. I'd appreciate some help:)

PS: I've heard about the [SharePoint Fluent Ribbon Api project](http://spribbon.codeplex.com/). I keep an eye on it, but I don't want to introduce new dependency in my project yet.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What I had to change:

1. Change the template of the dropdown list to o2:

   ```
   <DropDown 
       Id="MyProject.RichEditorCustomisation.SetupMyPlugin"
       Command="MyProject.Ribbon.PageComponent.DoSetupMyPlugin"
       QueryCommand="MyProject.Ribbon.PageComponent.QuerySetupMyPlugin"
       Sequence="31"
       Width="200px"
       Alt="TODO"
       TemplateAlias="o2" >
   ```
2. I also specified a menuItemID for each element :

   ```
   <Button  Id="MyProject.RichEditorCustomisation.SetupMyPlugin.DefaultButton"
       Command="MyProject.Ribbon.PageComponent.SetupMyPlugin"
       MenuItemId="SetupMyPlugin_DefaultButton"
       LabelText="Default" CommandValueId="0" 
       />
   ```
3. In the javascript file, I have to use the `this` keyword to call instance methods.
4. I also have to use the `CommandValueId` property to get my value, and not the `Value` property/

   ```
   case "MyProject.Ribbon.PageComponent.SetupMyPlugin":
       this.setMyPluginValue(properties["CommandValueId"]);
       break;
   ```
5. I also have to clear the browser cache each time I redeploy the solution.

   **At this point, the drowdown appears.**. However, the drop down list does not keep its value. Actually, everytime the QueryCommand is called, I return the correct value, but the dropdown does not reflect it.
6. Unfortunately, The xhtml sanitizer strips all `data-*` attributes (see [Publishing Rich HTML without any limitations in SharePoint 2010](http://blog.mastykarz.nl/publishing-rich-html-no-limitations-sharepoint-2010/) for further backgroung).

   So I also have to rewrite my plugin (fortunately the plugin is written for this project) to support either `data-*` or pseudo css class `<a class="myplugin mypluginvalue1">` construction.